# What is the point of using class as Derivation constraint - C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics

```
public void AddEmployee<T> (T employee) where T : Employee
{

  //some code here


 }
```

But if I write it like this

```
public void AddEmployee (Employee Employee)
{
 // Code here
}
```

Similarly,

```
public class GenericList<T> where T : Employee
```

and

```
public class GenericList<Employee>
```

I do not see any difference between two. I understand that when there is interface as derivation constraint like

```
public class GenericList<T> where T : IComparable, IConvertible
```

But if subclass used (as in employee above), that does not make sense to me. Am I missing something here? Please explain

Comment: I think your example of `GenericList<Employee>` is incorrect. In that case `Employee` is not a type, it is a generic parameter, which is as meaningfull as `T` or `E` or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About classes

This question is about the same question as: What is the difference between the non-generic `ArrayList` and the generic `List<T>`. Since ArrayList accepts any type of data (all are dervice from the baseclass `object`, it is easy to out the data in.

There is one big disadvantage: When you are pulling data out of the `ArrayList`, you have to cast it back to its original data type.

In you example goes the same thing. Lets say your are have a manager class:

```
public class Manager : Employee {}
```

And you you create to lists:

```
public class MyList: List<Emplyoyee> {}
public class MyList<T>: List<T> where T : Employee {}
...
MyList myList1 = ...;
MyList<Employee> myList2 = ...;
```

Both `myList1` and `myList2` willa accept `Employee` instances and `Manager` instances. So far no difference. (It would be same as comparing `ArrayList` and `List<object>`.)

But now try this:

```
MyList myList1 = ...;
MyList<Manager> myList2 = ...;
```

Both lists accept instance of the `Manager` type. But only `myList1` accepts also instances of type `Employee`. If you want to retrieve a manager from `myList1` you will probably need to cast it (degredation of performance). `myList2` is restricted to only accept managers (and derivatives).

In short: `MyList` can be used for any Employee-derivative and is not as restricting as `MyList<T>`. `MyList<T>` can be restrived to any type as long as it is derived from `Employee`. It

*If you are not planning to make a specialized list for managers, than in that case there will not be any difference.*

### About methods

You method examples are both a bit the same. Lets use some other example to demostrate the use:

```
void DoSomething1(object value) {};
void DoSomething2<T>(T value) {};
```

Both methods do accept ANY parameter. Exception, if you would use value types for `DoSomething1`, the value would be boxed. Boxing is a performance penalty. `DoSomething2` will adjust itself to its type. Thus:

```
DoSomething1(123); // <-- Will box the int.
DoSomething2(123); // <-- Will NOT box the int.
```

Another example:

```
object Copy1(object value) {};
T Copy2<T>(T value) {};
```

Both methods make a copy of the parameter and returns it (how, does not matter now). In the first example, an `object` is returned. If you would like to use the copy, your would have to cast it first. Perhaps unbox it. Both performance los. In the second Copy-method, your always get a value returned of the same type as the parameter. Thus:

```
int copy1 = (int)Copy1(123); // <-- Will box the int, and the copy needs to be unboxed.
int copy2 = Copy2(123); // <-- Will NOT box the int, and the copy does NOT need to be unboxed or casted.
```

*In your case, when you are only using input parameters that are reference types and not return types, it would not make much of a difference (with focus on performance).*

Comment: The restriction on MyList2 is based on the implementation, they can still use MyList<Employee>

Comment: @as1: I do not exactly understand what you mean by it. `MyList<Employee>` does not restrict it to accept values of type `Employee`. The generic type  `class MyList<Employee>` could easily be instantiated as `MyList<int> myList = ...`.

Comment: I kind of get it now. I was under impression (I don't know how) that List is stored as the basetype (in this case employee) and not the derived type (Manager). Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that `List<Employee>` can hold any instances of `Employee` or one of its subclasses, while a `List<T> where T : Employee` might be a more restrictive.

This is because the generic type `T` can be any subclass of `Employee`, and in that case the list can only contain instances of subclasses of `T`, and not any `Employee` instance.

For example, given

```
public class Manager : Employee
{
}
```

a `List<Manager>` can only hold managers, and not instance of the `Employee` base class, or some other subclass of `Employee`.

In contrast, you could put both `Employee` and `Manager` instances into a `List<Employee>`

Comment: Isn't List<Employee> and List<T>  where T:Employee same? Both can hold any subclass of Employee. Can you please clarify more?

Comment: @as1 - Which bit don't you understand? It's possible that `List<T> where T : Employee` might **not** be able to contain any subclass of employee, if `T` is a more derived type than `Employee` (such as the `Manager` class in the example). In that case it can only contain subclasses of the type `T`, not any `Employee`.

Comment: so if I get it correctly, those using the implementation has the ability to restrict it to derived type, but if they use List<Employee> (for List<T> implementation) it is essentially same, am I correct?

Comment: @as1 - Yes, if you specify `Employee` as the generic type `T` then it will be the same, but not if you make `T` a subclass of `Employee`.